# Android GraphView doesn't show series title

Tags: android, series, android-graphview

I implemented a graphview in my application that has 4 lineseries, but my graphview doesn't show series title in my chart, how could I fix that?
thanks in advance

Comment: show some code, link to library you are using so we can help you.

Answer (score 4):

Try: graph.getLegendRenderer().setVisible(true);